# Accessing Redmine controllers through a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, redmine

I've already asked the question on the Redmine official website but I didn't get any answer, maybe I'll have more chance here.

I'm working on a project and I try to improve an [existing plugin](https://github.com/alrick/Reddrop) for Redmine by adding some features to it to allow the user to upload his Dropbox files in the Redmine documents with a simple form. Redmine already has this possibilty so I would like to use the controller and methods already defined in the Redmine source code.

I have the following code in one of my plugin views:

```
<% html_title "Reddrop - Sync" %>
<h2>Synchronisation page</h2>
<p>Please choose your file</p>
<%= form_tag({:controller => "documents", :action => "add_attachment", :id => @document},    :multipart => true) do %>
<%= file_field_tag 'attachments[dummy][file]', :id => nil, :multiple => true, :onchange => "addInputFiles(this)" %>
<%= submit_tag(value = "Sync this file with Redmine") %>
<% end %>
```

I'm calling the "documents" controller and the `add_attachment` method which are defined in the Redmine source code. When I submit my form I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"add_attachment", :id=>nil}):
```

Is it possible to call these controllers/methods through a plugin if they are defined in the Redmine source code?

If yes, maybe could you give some advice to how configure my routes?

Comment: Your `@document` instance variable is `nil`. How do you set it?

Comment: Mmh there are probably some mistakes in the code, because I'm unable to try it. I can't answer you precisely now, let me check the full code.

Comment: Since it's not really an answer, I figured I'd just link to a plugin I wrote a while back that uses dropbox as Redmine's file storage backend. https://github.com/alexbevi/redmine_dropbox_attachments. Without more context, it's a bit difficult to provide a proper answer.
If you have a fork on Github you could point to so we could test it might be easier to answer this question.

Comment: I found another way to upload my files, and it's working pretty well but thanks for the link, I will for sure take a look.

Comment: well maybe the controllers are namespaced, try running `rake routes` and see what the routes are called and if they have namespaces or not.

Comment: Basically you need to recreate the `documents_controller.rb` on your project with the same path as the original one. I did the same to overwrite doorkeeper's controller. If the path is not exactly the same, you'll have a `No route matches` error.

Answer (score 1):

See here `:id => @document`
`@document` is the variable that contains `nil` however this should contain some `id` (like 1,2 or whatever) of required record check it in your controller and once you will fix this issue sure this error will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

validate route format
    `rake | rails  route`

send the expected parameters and the correct namespace. If you already have a @document you could use the form_for.

```
`<% form_for(@document, url: {action:'add_attachment'} ) do %> `
```